# Changing date format via VBA to SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, date

I have a question which I haven't been able to answer to far, my issue is that I have a macro that is using a SQL lookup to access a SQL database and pull information. Within excel it is always forcing the dates to DD/MM/YYYY (You can force the formatting but when it passes it to the SQL side of things it still comes out as DD/MM/YYYY even if the formatting visually looks correct).

I have tried a number of changes to my code to try and 'force' it however I have had no luck am I over complicating it or is it alot harder to do that it should be? lol.

I will provide my VB code and the "Properties" for what the 'connection' looks like that is made from using the macro.

As a note, the format needs to be YYYY-MM-DD as this is how its stored within the database. Currently the only way to get around it is to use a " ' " infront of the date for instance '2013-12-01 to force it or else it goes to 01/12/2013.

Any ideas? I have been racking my brain for far too long lol.

Regards Jamie

Server is a SQLEXPRESS server if that info is needed.

Code below:

```
Sub CustomisedSQLQuery()
'
' SQL Query to allow user customisation. 
'

'
Dim FileName As String
Dim User As String
Dim StartDate As String
Dim EndDate As String
Dim Category As String


Dim Confirm As Variant
Confirm = MsgBox("Have you made sure that at least one of the search criteria's is populated? If so your excel may crash or you may kill the database.", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Wait....")
If Confirm = vbNo Then ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input Sheet").Activate
If Confirm = vbNo Then Exit Sub



FileName = Worksheets("Input Sheet").Cells(10, 1)
User = Worksheets("Master DATA").Cells(1, 1)
StartDate = Worksheets("Input Sheet").Cells(10, 3)
EndDate = Worksheets("Input Sheet").Cells(10, 4)
Category = Worksheets("Master DATA").Cells(1, 5)

MyStr = Format(StartDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")
MyStr = Format(EndDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")

    Sheets("Output Sheet").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=SERVERADDRESS;UID=USERNAME;PWD=PASSWORD;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;WSID=ID" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT DocumentsRead.userID, DocumentsRead.fileName, DocumentsRead.category, DocumentsRead.downloadedByUser, DocumentsRead.timeDownloaded, DocumentsRead.timeR" _
        , _
        "ead" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM EndUsers.dbo.DocumentsRead DocumentsRead" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (DocumentsRead.fileName Like '" & FileName & "') AND (DocumentsRead.category='" & Category & "') AND (DocumentsRead.timeRead Is Null) " _
        , "AND (DocumentsRead.timeDownloaded Between {ts '" & StartDate & " 00:00:01'} An" _
        , "d {ts '" & EndDate & " 00:00:01'})")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

Sheets("Input Sheet").Select
End Sub
```

This is the connection properties from SQL

```
SELECT DocumentsRead.userID, DocumentsRead.fileName, DocumentsRead.category, DocumentsRead.downloadedByUser, DocumentsRead.timeDownloaded, DocumentsRead.timeRead
FROM EndUsers.dbo.DocumentsRead DocumentsRead
WHERE (DocumentsRead.fileName Like 'GB') AND (DocumentsRead.category='Notices') AND (DocumentsRead.timeRead Is Null) AND (DocumentsRead.timeDownloaded Between {ts '01/12/2013 00:00:01'} And {ts '08/11/2013 00:00:01'})
```

The input sheet looks as follows:

[image: Excel]

Comment: Are you saying that when the cell is updated, any formatting on the cell is removed and the sheet reverts to default excel date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your problem is in the formatting of the StartDate/EndDate. Here is your code:

```
MyStr = Format(StartDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")
MyStr = Format(EndDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Here is what I assume you want to be doing:

```
StartDate = Format(StartDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
EndDate = Format(EndDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

I believe you can also tell Access the string is a date by wrapping it in #. Such as

```
"and DocumentsRead.timeDownloaded >= #" & StartDate & "#" & vbcrlf & _
"and DocumentsRead.timeDownloaded <  #" & EndDate & "#"
```

Comment: That worked, just needed another set of eyes :). Thank you very much Pal.